# How to add a new button when onPressed is called?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an `Elevated Icon Button` that when pressed displays a `Dialog` that prompts a user to enter text and select an amount from a `NumberPicker`. The `showDialog` function is called that saves the user's entry in a TextEditingController:

[image]

How would I create a function that once the user saves their entry in `Dialog`, creates a new button that displays `TextEditingController.text` as shown in the below:

[image]

`_addItem` code:

```
  Future<void> _addItem(BuildContext context) async {
valueText = '';

return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Example'),
        content: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 150,
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    valueText = value;
                  });
                },
                controller: _textController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: '"Example"'),
              ),
            ),
            NumberPicker(
              value: _currentValue,
              minValue: 0,
              maxValue: 100,
              onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _currentValue = value),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('CANCEL'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              });
            },
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                codeDialog = valueText;
                Navigator.pop(context);
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
}
```

Currently the button updates to the `textEditingController.text`. I want to replace the Icon with the number selected by the user but I'll figure that out later. Probably best to just replace it with a conditional statement that renders a list of different buttons. They need to be buttons so they can be edited if needed before all data is sent to a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use statement in the `build` method of your `Stateful` widget

```
... State of your widget ...
final TextController _textController;
final int _currentValue;

Widget build(context) {
    return YourWidgetTree(
        child: Row(
            children: [
                ElevatedButton(child: Text('Add item')),
                if(_controller.text.isNotEmpty)
                    ElevatedButton(child: Text('$_currentValue ${_controller.text}', onPressed: (){ ... })),
            ])
        )
}

Future<void> _addItem(BuildContext context) {...}
```